# Unmirror accidentally mirrored remote repositories

Tags: git, mirror

Having these set of remotes and branches in them:

```
> git show-ref
... refs/heads/master
... refs/heads/old-master
... refs/remotes/bb/master
... refs/remotes/bb/old-master
... refs/remotes/gh/HEAD
... refs/remotes/gh/master
... refs/remotes/gh/old-master
... refs/remotes/sf/master
... refs/remotes/sf/old-master
```

`gh` is used as a main head, all other remotes as copies (branches mirror, not refs mirror).

These commands to pull and to allocate all refs has having no errors and warnings:

```
git pull gh *:*
git pull bb *:*
git pull sf *:*
```

But in one day one or more remotes has accidentally been mirrored:

```
git push gh --mirror
git push bb --mirror
git push sf --mirror
```

Or

```
git push gh *:*
git push bb *:*
git push sf *:*
```

Now a remote counter part falls into the mirror state and reports the warnings:

```
> git pull gh *:*
warning: refs/remotes/gh/master usually tracks refs/heads/master, not refs/remotes/gh/master
warning: refs/remotes/gh/old-master usually tracks refs/heads/old-master, not refs/remotes/gh/old-master
Already up to date.
```

Tried to delete all refs in the local and all remotes. But didn't work. Somehow a remote remembers the state.

Tried to reproduce with a single remote and it reports the same warnings.

Is there a way to unmirror a remote repository back?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem was in the logic of the push algorithm of an unmirror script.

There was 2 fors (pseudocode):

```py
for remote in remotes:
  for branch in branches:
    git_push([remote, ':refs/remotes/' + remote + '/' + branch])
```

Instead of 3 fors:

```py
for remote in remotes:
  for ref_remote in remotes:
    for branch in branches:
      git_push([remote, ':refs/remotes/' + ref_remote + '/' + branch])
```

Because each remote has `num(refs) = num(branches) x num(remotes)` after the mirror.

Shell scripts to automate unmirror:

https://github.com/andry81/gitcmd/tree/HEAD/git_unmirror_refs.sh
https://github.com/andry81/contools/tree/HEAD/Scripts/Tools/ToolAdaptors/app/git/git_unmirror_refs.bat